# How to use CSS selector with strings

Tags: selenium, findelement

I've been trying to create a program that finds data on a site using selenium. I've downloaded the webdriver and by module.

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("articlecount a"))
print(number)
```

When I run the code, it displays the error that the str object is not callable. (I'm assuming the error comes from the article count a part.

I've tried removing the two quotations around "articlecount a" but that just creates more errors.

Does anyone know what I have to do to allow the CSS Selector to extract data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("articlecount a"))
```

It should be like

```
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"articlecount a")
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1. The command you are trying to use has somewhat different syntax.
   Instead of

```py
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("articlecount a"))
```

It should be something like

```py
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"articlecount a")
```

2. Your locator is wrong.
   Instead of `articlecount a` it probably should be `#articlecount a`
3. You are missing a delay here. The best practice is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits
4. You need to extract the text value from `number` web element object.

With all the above your code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
number = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#articlecount a"))).text
print(number)
```

The output here will be

```
6,469,178
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#articlecount a")
print(number.text)
```